# Curl via SSL with client authentication

Tags: php, ssl, curl, logging

I am trying to open a connection from an host to another one using curl via openssl.
I absolutely want to verify the client AND the server with a custom CA certificate.

So I filled the curl options :

- CURLOPT_CAINFO
- CURLOPT_SSLKEY
- CURLOPT_SSLCERT

The connection is done but the variable SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CL is not filled whereas SSL_SERVER_S_DN_CL is properly filled.

Do you know what could have happened or where I can find logs because standard apache error logs don't give me information

Comment: Just to check, have you configured your server to request a client certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`curl_error($ch)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to produce a string with the error.

Comment: Thanks but the curl_error function returns an empty string... :(

Comment: Use `var_dump` to make sure it isn’t returning `null` or similar. Paste your code here so we can see it.